# Opportunity product and Quoteline item have the same behaviour

Tags: opportunity, relationships, opportunity-lineitem, quote

Can any one let me know .Opportunity has relatinship to opportunity product and quote object .Do opportunity product and quoteline item are related or do their have same behaviour or if different what is the difference.Please clarify.

Comment: Can you please clarify, what do you mean by behavior? Opportunity product and quote line item are not related to each other.....

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite now if I follow exactly what you are asking but here goes.

There is no true relationship between Opportunity product and the quote line items.  I don't know what quoting solution you are using, but in many of them the 'syncing' of a quote pushes the quote line items to opportunity line items on the opportunity.  These Opportunity line items contain products and the amount of the opportunity is updated.  This is how the quote line items are 'related' to opportunity products.